# simple template deduction error

Tags: c++, templates

I'm trying to automatically generate the `const` member function pair with some templates. Please help me compile this code.

```
template<typename T>
struct Constifier
{
  typedef T Type;
};

template<typename T>
struct Constifier<T &>
{
  typedef const T &Type;
};

template<typename T>
struct Constifier<T &&>
{
  typedef const T &&Type;
};

template<typename T>
struct Constifier<T *>
{
  typedef const T *Type;
};

template<typename F>
struct ReturnType;

template<typename R, typename ...Ts>
struct ReturnType<R (*)(Ts ...ts)>
{
  typedef R Type;
};

template<typename R, typename T, typename ...Ts>
struct ReturnType<R (T::*)(Ts ...ts)>
{
  typedef R Type;
};

template<typename T, typename F, typename ...Ts>
auto callConstVersion(const T *t, F f, Ts ...ts)
{
  return const_cast<typename Constifier<typename ReturnType<F>::Type>::Type>((const_cast<T *>(t)->*f)(ts...));
}

struct A
{
  A *p;
  A *get() {return p;}
  const A *get() const {return callConstVersion(this, &A::get);}
};
```

Comment: `get` is overloaded, you'd need something like `static_cast<const A*(A::*)()const>(&A::get)`

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki I was also thinking about that, but I can't think a way to distinguish the correct overloaded non-`const` `get`.

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki I'll try that.

Comment: this one is non-const `static_cast<A*(A::*)()>(&A::get)`

Comment: Why not implement the `const` version and call that from the non-const one?

Comment: @JorenHeit As far as I can tell, it is undefined behaviour to cast away constness and dereference the pointer/reference. I'll need to dig in the standard to be sure.

Comment: @xiver77 It's perfectly valid to call a const member from a non-const one. So if you want to avoid duplicate code, you can implement the const version, and call this from the non-const one without casts or hacks.

Comment: Oh wait, you're talking about the return type. Nevermind.

Comment: @JorenHeit I might have been wrong. A little confused now. I asked another question about this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32426504/const-to-non-const-or-non-const-to-const

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `get` member function is overloaded, thus, given `&A::get` as an argument, `F` becomes non-deducible. To disambiguate between the two use a `static_cast`:

```
static_cast<const A*(A::*)() const>(&A::get) // for the const overload

static_cast<A*(A::*)()>(&A::get) // for the non-const overload
```

or specify `F` explicitly in a template argument list:

```
callConstVersion<A,A*(A::*)()>(this, &A::get);
```

or if you know `callConstVersion` should always take a non-const non-volatile non-ref-qualified member function, you can redefine it as follows:

```
template<typename T, typename R, typename... Args, typename ...Ts>
auto callConstVersion(const T *t, R(T::*f)(Args...), Ts ...ts)
```

(then plain `callConstVersion(this, &A::get)` should work).