# `const` to non-`const` or non-`const` to `const`

Tags: c++, constants

The code below is used for reducing code duplication when there are both `const` and non-`const` getters. It creates the `const` version from non-`const`. I searched about this a bit and a lot of people are saying that I should instead create the non-`const` version from `const`.

My thought is that if I create the non-`const` version from the `const` version, opposite from the code below, it may be unsafe to dereference the returned pointer or reference which was originally `const`. I'm really not sure about this, so I'm asking for clarification, and what is the correct 'direction'?

```
template<typename T>
struct Constifier
{
  typedef T Type;
};

template<typename T>
struct Constifier<T &>
{
  typedef const T &Type;
};

template<typename T>
struct Constifier<T &&>
{
  typedef const T &&Type;
};

template<typename T>
struct Constifier<T *>
{
  typedef const T *Type;
};

template<typename F>
struct ReturnType;

template<typename R, typename ...Ts>
struct ReturnType<R (*)(Ts ...ts)>
{
  typedef R Type;
};

template<typename R, typename T, typename ...Ts>
struct ReturnType<R (T::*)(Ts ...ts)>
{
  typedef R Type;
};

template<typename T, typename F, typename ...Ts>
auto callConstVersion(const T *t, F f, Ts ...ts)
{
  return const_cast<typename Constifier<typename ReturnType<F>::Type>::Type>((const_cast<T *>(t)->*f)(ts...));
}

struct A
{
  A *p;
  A *get() {return p;}
  const A *get() const {return callConstVersion(this, static_cast<A *(A::*)()>(&A::get));}
};
```

Comment: What is the difference between this and [your last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32426161/simple-template-deduction-error)?

Comment: @CoryKramer What I'm asking is different. In the last one, I wanted to get my code compiled, and here I want to know something different with already compilable code.

Comment: The whole point of const is you are saying this is constant. Does not change. Compiler i am helping you. Then you want to tear that understanding up and thow it away

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should always create `non-const` version from `const` one and not in the opposit way. The explanation is simple, think of it this way:

You can call `non-const` getter only on the `non-const` object. If the object is `non-const`, you can safely `const_cast` your `const` getter inside the `non-const` method. Why? Because you can only call this method on `non-const` object.

Doing the opposit is not really safe, because when calling `non-const` method in the `const` one you cannot assure, that constness is preserved.